# Rails: two relationships from one model to other (alias)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Hi Im very new with active record and I do not know how to set up this relationships.

I have the model `orders` and the model `addresses`

an order can have many shipping_addresses and also can have many invoice_addresses

how can I set up this relationship? I mean invoice_addresses and shipping_addresses are basically the same, but I need to get them separately from the order

```
order.shipping_addresses
order.invoice_addresses
```

I do not want to create more models, I just need to know how to set up this relationship using just `order` and `address` models

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define multiple `has_many` to the same class as follows:

```
# app/models/order.rb

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :shipping_addresses, class_name: 'Address'
  has_many :invoice_addresses, class_name: 'Address'
  ...
end
```

If you want to add conditions to these associtions then please see [Active Record Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) for details.

Comment: Hi thank you so much, I just have another question, how should be the migration in the Address model? only one 'order_id'  column? and rails will know what is the scope?

Comment: and in Address model I just need to define 'belongs_to :order' ?

Comment: Do you really want "order has_many address" or "order belongs_to shipping address" and "order belongs to invoice address".

Comment: I do not have idea how it worked but your solution works like a charm!! just added order_id column to addresses table and also added belongs_to order to address model and it worked!! Im really lost how it worked =S

Comment: Please make sure to read the linked article until you find out how it worked.

Comment: Yea you rock bro! thank you, I now how it is working, I could check in the database